# Vanilla Javascript, mouseout delay with cancelation without jQuery

Tags: javascript

i am currently having a problem. I am using css to hide and display elements depending on the mouse function. One of my elements (a navigation arrow) depends on some other things. I now need a cancleable timer function which counts for lets say 2 seconds on mouseleave and then changes the class attribute. But it should have a timer which cancels on mouseover immediately. I dont want it to disappear too early.
Below my code with which i tried so far. I have no idea how to access the current timings of that setIntervall stuff. I alreasy experimented with Date.now(). But now i hope some of the geeks is able to help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
function hideElementOnMouseOut(el)
{
    el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event )
    {   
        mySlideAction = setInterval( function()
        {

        }, 1000 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize interval on `mouseleave` function and clear this interval on `mouseover` function, which would prevent executing it's function.

Check the snippet below.

```js
function hideElementOnMouseOut(el)
{
    var interval;
  
    el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event)
    {   
        el.innerHTML = 'mouse out';
        interval = setInterval(function()
        {
            el.innerHTML = 'time out';
            el.className = 'out';
        }, 1000);
    });
                        
    el.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event)  
    {
        el.innerHTML = 'mouse in';
        el.className = '';
        if(interval) {              
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
  
}
                        
hideElementOnMouseOut(document.getElementById("element"));
```

```css
#element {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red; 
}

#element.out {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```